# MySQL query with two boolean conditions takes way longer than querying each condition separat

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, execution-time

I have a MySQL database with a table with about 160.000 entries. When I query the following queries it takes about 0.5 seconds of exeuction time:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) > 18;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) < 3;
```

After combining the statements into a single query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) > 18 OR EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) < 3;
```

the execution takes forever. In fact I haven't seen the query finish execution and canceld it after about 20 minutes.

When I change the OR to AND for example like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) > 10 AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) < 19;
```

Execution time is in the milliseconds again.

Can somenone please explain this odd behavior and maybe suggest a solution to querying the two conditions with OR.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) not between 3 and 18;
```

Answer (score 3):

The performances of a query like yours cannot be optimal: you are using a function on a date column, and even if the date column is indexed, the index cannot be used.

As a simple workaround I would try with an union all query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) > 18
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date) < 3
```

while logically equivalent to the OR form, it might perform better... but it also might not!

A proper solution is to *add a new hour column*, with an *index on it*:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN date_hour INT;
ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX idx_date (date_hour);

/* do an update once... or use a trigger */
UPDATE table SET date_hour = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date);

SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_hour > 18 or date_hour < 3;
```